# Received a visa for India but never used it. If I wish to travel to India now, how should I apply for a new visa?

Tags: visas, india, tourist-visas

I wish to travel to India in November from Bangladesh. I have an issue: I had visa for India from November till May 2015. I had to travel to the UK 3 times in this period so couldn't manage to travel to India. Now I wish to travel again.

My questions are:

1. Is there any implication this time of not travelling to India even if applying for a visa?
2. Do I need to write any explanation letter with this application?
3. In the form, it asks for the information "Have you ever traveled to India?". I got the visa but didn't travel, so what should I put in that field?

Answer (score 2):

Same way you applied for it the first time.

A visa grants you permission to travel to said country. It doesn't mean you have to use it.

If you then wish to travel there again (presumably after the dates of your previous visa) that's fine.

So in short:

1. None. There's no issue - once you get the visa, it's up to you -
   you don't have to travel or use it.
2. No you do not.
3. "No". You got a visa, but you didn't travel to India. There's nothing wrong with that - and you should always answer truthfully. So have you travelled to India? No, you have not.

Hope that helps.